# can i run a node function on a react app directly

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am making a react app where I need to fetch some data using an API.

I want to deploy this app with Netlify so I cannot use a backend. So, I wrote a Firebase Cloud Function to handle the fetching. However, Google wouldn't allow third-party API requests on the free plan.

So either I have to learn using AWS or I will write a backend and deploy using another service.

Honestly, I don't want to do either. So, my question is, can I call this node function directly inside my react app if so how and is it advisable, if not are there any other alternatives?

The function is something like this:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const League = require("leagueapiwrapper");
require("dotenv").config();

exports.getFavorites = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  try {
    const LeagueAPI = new League(process.env.API_KEY, Region.TR);
...
```

The only thing that actually requires node is the `leagueapiwrapper` package. (Obviously I will get rid of firebase related stuff).

Comment: you can initialize your react app with firebase and interact with firebase using the cli as opposed to having to use cloud functions

Comment: would that be possible to work with during deployment? @RobertTerrell

Comment: yes I've done this multiple times, the client side firebase cli is definitely what you are looking for if you can't deploy a back end

Comment: it basically offers you everything cloud functions offer aside from certain features the admin sdk brings to the table

Comment: how can i figure out how to do it? is there a good link you can give me? @RobertTerrell

Comment: https://medium.com/@joeponzio/the-right-way-to-add-firebase-to-your-react-project-using-react-hooks-a32db20bf1a0